# psycopg2 connecting to postgresql database - error

Tags: python, postgresql

I have problem to connect to my postgreSQL database.
I have `databasename`, `password`, `hostname`, `port` and I use this:

```py
conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='my_database' user='postgres' password='secret'"
```

But I got error like this:

> *Is the server running on host "...." and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432*

I don't know if I used correctly host, I insert the value of hostname.
What is the difference between hostname and host? Anyone could help me?

Comment: Why did you censor the Error message?  If it just said `"localhost" (127.0.0.1) ` there is nothing that needs to be censored, and if said something else that would be important for us to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, user=user, password=password, host=postgres_address, port=postgres_port)
```

This is working example to connect, you must define early dbname, user, password, postgres_address. If you have connection error, you can use ping for testing connection and telnet for testing openning port. Or you can use Beaver for test connection to postgres server.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your database has a firewall, be sure to whitelist the IP you are trying to connect from.

Answer (score 0):

#### Difference of `host` and `hostname`

The difference of `host` and `hostname` really depends on the context. In your context of `psycopg2` and `PostgreSQL` connection, the `host` normally means the IP address of the PostgreSQL server or the resolvable name of the PostgreSQL server such as DNS name if it has. If you are running linux server, the output of command `hostname` is unlikely to work in your case.

#### `psycopg2` connection

Your connection string looks OK. But I will suggest you to use below connection format:

```py
import psycopg2
try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "sysadmin",
                                  password = "pynative@#29",
                                  host = "127.0.0.1",
                                  port = "5432",
                                  database = "postgres_db")
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error :
    print ("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)
```

You should use the IP address as the `host` value.

#### Troubleshooting

In the case of connection error, you should use other tools to test the connection of PostgreSQL server such as `psql`, `pgAdmin4` or `DBeaver`.

You can also use `telnet` or `netcat` tools to test the network connection of PostgreSQL server, such as

```sh
telnet PostgreSQL_ip_address 5432

nc -v PostgreSQL_ip_address 5432
```